# Instantiating QgsFeatureFilterModel using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

When I try to create an instance of QgsFeatureFilterModel with PyQGIS like this:

```
self._model = QgsFeatureFilterModel()
```

I got this message:

> QgsFeatureFilterModel represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated

This definitely works in the older QGIS version (3.6), but after upgrade to 3.14, it starts to complain.

What is the proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need to use the abstract class to create your own class like below. Your issue seems more related to Python than QGIS except the breaking API change. As I don't know the reason for API change, I don't know it you need to reimplement some of it methods.

```py
class MyOwnQgsFeatureFilterModel(QgsFeatureFilterModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

self._model = MyOwnQgsFeatureFilterModel()
```

Comment: There was major rework of this class at version 3.14. Not able to instantiate it since then. But, C++ API says nothing about abstract class. Confusing, probably SIP related issue... After all creating subclass does work, so I will stick with this until I get clear answer from devs...

Comment: Some clues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330350/c-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-error Could be related to `QgsFeatureFilterModel` inheriting in recent QGIS version from `QgsFeaturePickerModelBase` if not all methods implemented