# qgis._core.QgsLayoutTable represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, table, c++

When i try to access the QgsLayoutTable class it says that it is abstract, but in the  [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Layout/QgsLayoutTable.html) it is referred as a builder exactly as a QgsLayoutItemTextTable or QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable. Deriving my own class from like [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390955/instantiating-qgsfeaturefiltermodel-using-pyqgis) leads QGIS to crash.
Am I missing something or the class might not work as intended?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = str(feat[0])                 
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()

for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

table1pg2 = QgsLayoutTable(layout)
layout.addMultiFrame(table1pg2)
```

Comment: I think you want to use `QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable` instead of `QgsLayoutTable`

Comment: The goal is to create a table that could be modified in the near future, without the need to access the layer, i tired to add a Text table, but with that i cannot access the item properties from the layout, so I am trying to add a "fixed table" using pyqgis

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is more correct:

```
while manager.layoutByName(layoutName) != None:
  manager.removeLayout(manager.layoutByName(layoutName))
```